# How I can extract function type without its different qualifiers?

Tags: c++, templates

As everyone knows, function type has different qualifiers: `const`, `volatile`, `noexcept`, `&` and `&&`. All these qualifiers are part of function type, so if I try to specialize for a function type like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct S{};

template<typename Cls, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct S<Ret (Cls::*)(Args...)> {
  //...
};
```

this specialization will be ignored if member function is `const`. I wonder if there is any way to extract member function type signature without qualifiers easily in STL? I can use SFINAE to create something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct function_traits {};

template<typename Cls, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Ret (Cls::*)(Args...)> {
    using unqualified_type = Ret (Cls::*)(Args...);
};

template<typename Cls, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Ret (Cls::*)(Args...) const> {
    using unqualified_type = Ret (Cls::*)(Args...);
};
//...
```

but it needs 48 specialization(like complex version of `std::is_function`). I wonder if there is any simpler way.

Comment: Can you please provide more background on what your ultimate goal is? (What is S used for?) This might be an XY problem.

Comment: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides) has some promising deduction guides. But I wouldn't want to abuse `std::function` for this, and would rather generate 48 (or was it 96?) specializations with macros.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That or write a small codegenerator so you can always debug against the actual (generated) code (more readable IMO). But I'm also curious what the answer to idmean's question is.

Comment: @idmean There are several reasons for a specialization for member function pointers. For example, extracting list of arguments. Problem is that how we can write a general specialization for members function pointers simpler.

Comment: If you write the specializations, you might as well do it once and have all the information you'll ever need out of them. Thankfully, some libraries such as [Boost.CallableTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html) have already done this.

Comment: @chris thanks for the link. it is strange that this part of boost is not added to the standard....

Comment: @Afshin, I'm not sure off the top of my head if it's ever been proposed. If not, anyone is free to do that. However, it's unlikely at this point given that reflection should cover it whenever it's ready.